# Dynamically Generate Formatted Template with HTML Input via Dreamweaver or Web service

Tags: html, css, dynamically-generated

Greetings Stackoverflow community,

**The Scenario**

An Cloud-based Inventory software outputs labels for print into an HTML file with numerous iterations of the following `<div>` enclosed HTML/CSS formatted labels.  I have 2"x1" labels in tables of 4x10 on 8.5x11 sheets with specific margins.  I've been using Screen Clipper & Adobe Photoshop to capture the labels on screen and put them into a file formatted specifically for these printable sheets.  I will not be working with this business in 5 months, and will need to make this process automatic for them to continue printing labels after I leave.

**The Conundrum**

Is there a means of dynamically formatting the HTML document into printable 4x10 tables with specified margins for ease of printing directly to the 8.5x11 label sheets with Dreamweaver?  IE can this code be copied into Dreamweaver or a web-based service that will wrap every `<div class="label size200x100 custom_margin">` in `<td>` tags, and every 4 `<td>` in `<tr>` tags up to 10 `<tr>` per page, and include preformatted CSS to account for the 8.5x11 margins and be able to do this 100's of times over for large orders where many labels need to be printed?

```
<div class="label size200x100 custom_margin">
<article>
                    <h1>STCo</h1>
                    <div class="price">
 <p class="saleprice"><sup class="currency">$</sup>1875</p></div>
 <p class="description"> i>NC55</i>Reclaimed pine oval end trestle table</p>
                </article>
 <footer class="barcode">
 <img class="ean8" src="./Lightspeed Retail PrintLabelTest_files/barcode(2).php">
 <img class="ean" src="./Lightspeed Retail - rintLabelTest_files/barcode(3).php">
 </footer>
</div>
</div>
```